# Auth token for utility account was changed unexpectedly

Tags: desire2learn

After the D2L outage on Monday (Sept 3, 2012), our application had been getting errors from the Valence API.  We use an utility account to access the API for this non-interactive application, and we found out that the UserID and UserKey were changed unexpectedly for this account.  The account and application were only created recently.  We did not change the password for this account, and we had already set "d2l.Security.Api.TokenTimeout" in the DOME to -1 (never expired).

Has anyone seen this problem?  Was the change caused by the unexpected system outage?  Or are we still missing something in our settings?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several conditions that will cause a user-authentication token rollover:

- TokenTimeout period, if set, has expired.
- User has changed their password, or someone else (admin) has changed their password.
- An admin has prompted the system to force a token expiry (by using the user management tool to select one or more users and "revoke application access" for that user -- this will invalidate the current user tokens forcing the users' third-party applications to re-validate and request new tokens).
- A database restore occurred to a checkpoint *before* the version of the data that contained a user's token timestamp entry

Note that any user tokens issued *before* setting the TokenTimeout period to infinity are *still subject to the timeout period under which they were first issued*. In other words, if you generated tokens for your utility account, and *then* set your TokenTimeout period to -1, your utility account's tokens *will* expire (after the expiry of the period under which they were created).

Based on your question it sounds like none of these appear to pertain to your case. Are there *other* user accounts that still have usable tokens? If you need to determine exactly what happened to the token expiry values in this particular case for this particular utility account of yours, you'll need to open a support incident with D2L, because it will require examination of your service and its database.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that maybe the token would expire after every system maintenance or restart, but this doesn't seem to be the case. We do not know if the tokens were changed for any other user accounts.  You're right that none of the items pertain to our case, but thanks so much for the info though. We've opened a support incident with D2L a few days ago already. Hope they'll be able to find more details about our case.

Comment: Btw, how does an admin prompt the system to force a token expiry?

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- answer improved to include detail on forced user token expiry.